# Swift: escape characters appear in json string

Tags: ios, swift, rest

I'm constructing a JSON string by concatenating strings. To get the quotes correct for the web service (no quotes around numbers), I'm using escape characters. When I print the resulting string in Xcode, it looks fine.

```
{"number":999,"name":"new"}
```

But when I use Wireshark to capture what's going over the wire, I can see the escape characters in the string.

```
"{\"number\":999,\"name\":\"new\"}"
```

Here's the code that creates the string:

```
let jsonString:String = "{\"number\":" + num + ",\"name\":\"" + name + "\"}"
```

How can I create the string so the escape characters aren't there?
Thanks

Comment: How do you sent the string? (Any reason not to use NSJSONSerialization instead of the "manual" JSON creation?)

Comment: I'm trying to create the JSON this way because the web service expects a certain order for the JSON. Swift dictionaries aren't ordered so when I tried it using a dictionary, it didn't work.

Comment: The server should not care about the order in a JSON dictionary, but that will not help you here. – But as I said above, more information is needed. The `jsonString` is correct, so there are only 2 possibilities: 1) The sent data is actually correct (as conjectured in the answer) 2) The sent data is wrong. So we need to know what methods are used to send the String variable over the network.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I fixed this server side. Here's the reason: "Why does it happen: MongoDB uses a binary data format called BSON. In BSON, the order of keys always matters. Notice, in JSON an object is an unordered set of key/value pairs." http://devblog.me/wtf-mongo

Comment: which swift version? 3.0 or 2.x?

Answer (score 1):

The reason I couldn't send the JSON as a dictionary is that Swift dictionaries are unordered. In this case, the server is using MongoDB. I fixed the issue server side instead of trying to hack around it in the client.

Here's the reason: "Why does it happen: MongoDB uses a binary data format called BSON. In BSON, the order of keys always matters. Notice, in JSON an object is an unordered set of key/value pairs." 
http://devblog.me/wtf-mongo

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that the escape characters are being inserted by Wireshark in it's own output.

Comment: When I use Postman, the escape characters aren't there, so I don't think it's Wireshark